# extend .list-unstyled with Bootstrap 4 is failing

Tags: css, sass, twitter-bootstrap-4, yarnpkg, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I install Bootstrap 4.0.0.0 alpha6 on Rails 5.1 with Yarn.
I post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43857468/install-with-yarn-bootstrap4-0-0-alpha-6-on-rails-5-1) how I installed.
So In my .SCSS I'm trying to do some unestyled list with bootstrap 4.

```
 ul.actions {
    @extend .list-unstyled;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    right: 2px;
    max-width: 45%;
    text-align: right;
 }
```

And I having an error:

```
"ul.actions" failed to @extend ".list-unstyled".
The selector ".list-unstyled" was not found.
Use "@extend .list-unstyled !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.
```

So if I put on my `index.html.slim`

```
ul.actions.list-unstyle
```

The unstyled list works. What happened here? Was because it wasn't installed with bootstrap-sass gem? I try with `@include list-unstyled;` and nothing. How can I use this in my case?